# I can't run the app after updating xcode13.1 Flutter Build error: @available

Tags: xcode, flutter

welcome all
At first. It was working properly. But yesterday I updated xcode 13.1

Where did the problems start?
I don't know why, but I deleted the project and restarted it. The same problem persists.

Tried many solutions, including deleting pods, but the same problem remains.

```
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    --- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:dvtdevice-DVTiOSDeviceSimulatorPlaceholder-iphonesimulator:placeholder, name:Any iOS Simulator Device }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:87794D66-56EF-4031-9C6F-9000B3146828, OS:15.0, name:iPad (9th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:56CAA1D1-D467-4AA0-9590-37CA951CE31D, OS:15.0, name:iPad Air (4th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:07CD56CD-EF32-4C8B-A96E-C8B0322850A9, OS:15.0, name:iPad Pro (9.7-inch) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:8034DB2A-554A-4508-804F-A82FA438E488, OS:15.0, name:iPad Pro (11-inch) (3rd generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:AED28544-86C1-4CFD-AC90-27E062266A68, OS:15.0, name:iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (5th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:E47912D5-AC56-4C48-9936-7BA6511D1E04, OS:15.0, name:iPad mini (6th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:3CE250F1-8ADA-4894-AF9B-1012B0DC84E4, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 8 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:DA3CBBF5-5A09-47A6-ACCF-E8D580F4D1AC, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 8 Plus }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:D91EFF3E-59B0-46BA-A499-73A5885055E4, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 11 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:153F25DB-84ED-4CDD-9EF0-3942B0F7676C, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 11 Pro }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:AA1FFB55-112C-4C8B-862D-2BDBF71BE5A3, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 11 Pro Max }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:AE61E638-B018-494A-8C0B-6BEF66E8E397, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 12 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:D19F7D13-F5D4-4C0C-B0E4-3BB6428D99C4, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 12 Pro }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:E395C189-6ACA-4AF3-800B-9FC676C033B9, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 12 Pro Max }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:61CE5713-8996-4AF9-BA67-A852C6DCECFD, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 12 mini }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:9A26D90C-D0AC-4A57-98BA-3408D709C9A0, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 13 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:537FD953-4572-418F-8C19-CA9809563B10, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 13 Pro }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:D9EC53C3-5F4B-4BA2-9A1A-6CAE2B18A6CC, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 13 Pro Max }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:CA45CEE0-BBCE-4D24-AFBE-FE6134ACEFC4, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 13 mini }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:86815B02-4070-4CFB-BFF3-9C77C561202C, OS:15.0, name:iPhone SE (2nd generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:33640CB1-029D-40AE-8F8F-8460E615EA08, OS:15.0, name:iPod touch (7th generation) }
    { platform:macOS, arch:arm64, variant:Designed for [iPad,iPhone], id:00008103-0006704C2262001E }
    { platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Any iOS Device }
    ** BUILD FAILED **


/Users/ashourofficiall/Devoloper/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sign_in_with_apple-3.0.0/ios/Classes/SignInWithAppleError.swift:42:6: error: enum cases with associated values cannot be marked potentially unavailable with '@available'
        @available(iOS 13.0, macOS 10.15, *)
         ^
/Users/ashourofficiall/Devoloper/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sign_in_with_apple-3.0.0/ios/Classes/SignInWithAppleError.swift:82:13: warning: switch must be exhaustive
                switch code {
                ^
/Users/ashourofficiall/Devoloper/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sign_in_with_apple-3.0.0/ios/Classes/SignInWithAppleError.swift:82:13: note: do you want to add missing cases?
                switch code {
                ^
/Users/ashourofficiall/Devoloper/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sign_in_with_apple-3.0.0/ios/Classes/SignInWithAppleError.swift:26:6: error: enum cases with associated values cannot be marked potentially unavailable with '@available'
        @available(iOS 13.0, macOS 10.15, *)
         ^
/Users/ashourofficiall/Devoloper/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sign_in_with_apple-3.0.0/ios/Classes/SignInWithAppleError.swift:30:6: error: enum cases with associated values cannot be marked potentially unavailable with '@available'
        @available(iOS 13.0, macOS 10.15, *)
         ^
/Users/ashourofficiall/Devoloper/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sign_in_with_apple-3.0.0/ios/Classes/SignInWithAppleError.swift:36:6: error: enum cases with associated values cannot be marked potentially unavailable with '@available'
        @available(iOS 13.0, macOS 10.15, *)
         ^
/Users/ashourofficiall/Devoloper/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sign_in_with_apple-3.0.0/ios/Classes/SignInWithAppleError.swift:42:6: error: enum cases with associated values cannot be marked potentially unavailable with '@available'
        @available(iOS 13.0, macOS 10.15, *)
         ^
/Users/ashourofficiall/Devoloper/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sign_in_with_apple-3.0.0/ios/Classes/SignInWithAppleError.swift:82:13: warning: switch must be exhaustive
                switch code {
                ^
/Users/ashourofficiall/Devoloper/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sign_in_with_apple-3.0.0/ios/Classes/SignInWithAppleError.swift:82:13: note: do you want to add missing cases?
                switch code {
                ^
/Users/ashourofficiall/Devoloper/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/local_auth-1.1.6/ios/Classes/FLTLocalAuthPlugin.m:85:56: warning: 'openURL:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please upgrade to version 3.1.0 of sign_in_with_apple

Comment: its work in ^3.2.0 ty